# BibLaTeX citetracker but with chapter numbers?

Tags: biblatex, pageref, verbose-note

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{c1, author={Author}, title={Article}}
    @misc{c2, author={Writer}, title={Book}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-note,citetracker=true,pageref=true]{biblatex}

\makepagenote
\let\footnote\pagenote

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

Filler text.\footcite{c1}

\chapter{Two}

Filler text.\footcite{c2}

More text.\footcite{c1}

\backmatter
\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

In this book, there is no separate bibliography; all references are printed in endnotes.  When a citation occurs more than once, I can use the `citetracker` option to refer to the endnote where the first, full citation can be found.

The endnotes are output like this:

```
Notes

Chapter 1 One
1. Author. Article.

Chapter 2 Two
1. Writer. Book.
2. Author, see n. 1.
```

But this is confusing, since there are two n. 1 notes on the page!  The reader has to recognize that the n. 1 he is looking for is in another chapter.

With the `pageref` option the page number of the endnote can also be printed, which helps in larger documents, except that there may be more than one n. 1 on the page that n. 2 refers to.

Is there a way to print the chapter number instead (or in addition to) the page number?  That is, n. 2 should look like either

```
2. Author, see ch. 1, n. 1.
```

or

```
2. Author, see ch. 1, n. 1, p 1.
```